# What's the syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run this code but I get more than one row back (which is what I want) but apparently the := operator can only handle one value. What do I need to get multiple rows back (one column) so that I can shove it into the next select statement

```
set @oids :=(

    SELECT OBJECT_ID
    FROM aaa K
    WHERE K.TYPE IN ('ISSN', 'ISBN') 
    GROUP BY K.OBJECT_ID
    HAVING count(distinct K.TYPE) = 2

);

select * 
from aaa
where OBJECT_ID in (@oids);
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a single query with no variables

```
select * 
from aaa
where OBJECT_ID in (SELECT OBJECT_ID
                    FROM aaa K
                    WHERE K.`TYPE` IN ('ISSN', 'ISBN') 
                    GROUP BY K.OBJECT_ID
                    HAVING count(distinct K.TYPE) = 2
                   );
```

Comment: can't use a single query. It's too taxing on the system.